# Using a color variation in a component color attribute is not working

Tags: ionic-framework

In an Ionic v4 app, I have a label component where I want to apply the `secondary-shade` color, but it doesn't work if I want to apply it directly from the `color` attribute.

This is how I am applying the color:

```
<ion-label color="secondary-shade">Secondary shade Label</ion-label>
```

Applying the color from the CSS is working though:

```
ion-label {
  --color: var(--ion-color-secondary-shade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give **secondary-shade color** using `color` attribute directly, you need to define **secondary-shade color** inside **`variables.scss`**.

Go to **src/theme/variables.scss** and add your **secondary-shade color** to **`$colors`** as below.

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  secondary-shade: #f53dc7
);
```

**Now you can use it as you preferred.**

```
<ion-label color="secondary-shade">Secondary shade Label</ion-label>
```

Comment: I am using an ionic 4 app (I have just mentioned it in the question). Inside **variables.scss**  and under the `:root` selector, the `secondary-shade` color is defined by default with the variable `--ion-color-secondary-shade`